# What is the correct technical term for code not running in CIL?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I understand the difference between CIL and code running in X++, but what is the correct technical term for code not running in the CIL?  And what about these other ones?

"It will run correctly in `[what term]`, but not when executing in CIL?"

"Code running in interop"...does this mean in CIL?

"Code compiled to p-code"...?

Any other misc terms I'm missing?

Comment: Me and my team used to refer to code not running in CIL as "Interpreted code".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client and server (when not in CIL) runs *P-Code*.